# I don't know how to use range in Python

Tags: python, range

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
age = input("What is your age?")
if age in range (18,30):
      print("You are young")
else:
      print("You are old")
```

What's wrong here? How do I do this range thing properly?

Comment: You need to cast input to an int, eg int(input(..))

Comment: What error are you getting. You need to add conditions for less than 18.

Comment: use `18 <= int(age) < 30`

Answer (score 0):

As Devesh said, you need to cast age as an integer by using `int(age)`. Furthermore, there is a space between `range` and `(18,30)` which shouldn't exist.
Change it into:

```
age = int(input("What is your age?"))
if age in range(18,30):
      print("You are young")
else:
      print("You are old")
```

Comment: input less than 18 will print `You are old`

Comment: Yes but since the input was not sanitized (the user could enter negative numbers of even letters and special characters), this is not the only thing which should be fixed but this is another problem

Comment: This is what I'm doing :

income = int(input("What is your annual gross income?"))
age = int(input("What is your age?"))
if age in range(18,30):
   if income in range (70000, **this is where I want to put infinite**):
     print("You are eligible for a loan!")
else:
     print("Sorry, you are not eligible for a loan.")

Is there a way I can represent infinity here?

Comment: You're looking for float('int')